# Powershell New-Service gives permission denied

Tags: powershell

Borrowed from the Microsoft example code:

```
function myService() {
  New-Service -Name "MyService" -BinaryPathName "c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs"
}

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -Wait -ArgumentList '-Command',"$(myService)"
```

> New-Service: Service cannot be created due to the following error: Access is denied.

This is strange because I thought `-RunAs` made me Administrator.

Is there something else I need to do to start a service?

Comment: Can you run the PowerShell itself as administrator ?

Comment: @HariHaran I can run other commands inside the function that is run as administrator.  Is that the same thing as running powershell itself as admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are running myService function in the current powershell instance and not in the new one you are opening.
$(myService) is a expression which because its surrounded by double " is run in the current powershell instance and the results are passed to the Start-Process instance.

You need to pass that function as a string to the Start-Process

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -Wait -ArgumentList '-Command',"function myService() {New-Service -Name 'MyService' -BinaryPathName 'c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs'};myService"
```

you could also make the function into a string before hand and pass it in double qoutes "

```
$Function1 = @"
function myService() {
    New-Service -Name 'MyService' -BinaryPathName 'c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs'
}
"@
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -Wait -ArgumentList '-Command',"$Function1;myService;pause"
```

Comment: what if I want to pass a variable value to the function to be used on the command line?

Comment: That sounds like a whole other question. BUT you must pass everything by string so if it was `function myService($Name)` you would `myService -name 'helloWorld'`. So something like `-argumentslist "function MyService($name){Function Code Here};MyService -Name 'helloWorld'"`